# Jquery always function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just have a quick question about jquery's always function.

Currently in my code I have a POST request so I'm using the `always` function to make it wait until it's done, then print out the response.

```
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log(ajax_send);
}
```

My question is that if I have some code which I wants to be run AFTER the POST request's finished, would it run before the `always` is done if I place it outside the loop like this:

```
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log(ajax_send);
}
console.log("ajax done");
```

if I will always have something inside the `always` function waiting for it.

I'm doing this because I'll be doing several POST request, and if I have to keep it inside the always it'll look very ugly, like this:

```
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("1");
    ajax_send.always(function(){
        console.log("2");
        ajax_send.always(function(){
            console.log("3");
        }
    }
}
```

If I can place it after and as long as I have something inside the `always` it'll still run AFTER the requests are done, the code'll look much nice, like this:

```
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("1");
}    
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("2");
}    
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("3");
}
```

Edit: My code above's missing the actual calls, but `.always` will always be after a POST request.

Comment: If you place the console outside the always, it will run before the Ajax call is made...

Comment: I meant place if after the `always`, not before the `always`

Comment: Isn't that function made for this?

Comment: what is the purpose of multiple always? Don;t you need to have it linked to the individual Ajax requests and not all to the same one? SOunds like you should be using jQuery.when()

Comment: @epascarello: I'm only putting it like that as illustration. Before each always there'll always be a different POST request, I just didn't include it in my code above

Answer (score 0):

the code inside of `always` will execute after that specific ajax call completes. The order in which your ajax calls return can't be determined so doing this:

```
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("1");
}    
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("2");
}    
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("3");
}
```

will not always be guaranteed to print out 1,2,3. The only way to do that is with:

```
ajax_send.always(function(){
    console.log("1");
    ajax_send.always(function(){
        console.log("2");
        ajax_send.always(function(){
            console.log("3");
        }
    }
}
```

The reason for this is that [ajax](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) calls (as their name implies) are asynchronous. This means they do not block the execution of your code, and instead do their work in the background so to speak. The purpose of `always` is to wait until that "background" function has finished doing what it's doing, and then execute the code you want. This ensures that things execute in the order you expect.

To do something similar to what you are asking for, look into using jQuery's [`when()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) function

Comment: Damn that sucks. I was hoping that it'd do that :( Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

```
var a = $.ajax(...),
    b = $.ajax(...),
    c  = $.ajax(...);

$.when(a, b, c).done( function() {
    console.log("Ajax calls are done");
});
```